# Trends data: web application frameworks popularity

Tags: data-request

There are various organization publishing [popularity data for programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_programming_language_popularity). Such data usually encompasses search volume, number of job offers, number of professionals, volume of code edited per year.

Is there similar popularity data for [Web application frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)?

[image: TIOBE index]

Examples of popular Web application frameworks: Django, Ruby on Rails, Struts 2, Wicket, JSF, Grails, Spring Framework, Play Framework, AngularJS, etc.

Comment: Not so useful, but job trends: http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=django%2C+jquery%2C+ajax&l=

Comment: Nice! That gives: http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=Django%2C+Ruby+on+Rails%2C+Struts+2%2C+Wicket%2C+JSF%2C+Grails%2C+Spring+Framework%2C+Play+Framework%2C+AngularJS&l= it requires knowing all Web Frameworks in advance, though.

Comment: and it's not machine readable...

Comment: Could use this http://www.digitizeit.de/ to make it machine readable

Comment: Some of these are easily detected from the page itself (especially the javascript frameworks), so it might be possible to extract from spidered data ... unfortunately, I have no idea how you'd run those sort of searches against something like Archive.org.  You might be able to get current adoption info from Google.

Comment: Actually, scratch that ... as you couldn't easily distill it down to the number of sites using a given technology, larger ones would overwhelm everything.

Comment: @Joe: Sorry, I just made my question more explicit, it is only about Web application frameworks, not about JavaScript frameworks (except server-side ones like NodeJS or AngularJS). So it is not obvious to tell from the publicly-visible part of existing websites.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul : there might still be some tell-tale signs.  There's a concept of 'hacking via google' where you use Google to search for these signs to identify exploitable back-ends.  There are some tools out there for 'fingerprinting' servers : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fingerprint_Web_Application_Framework_(OTG-INFO-008)